# DHTML - Show picture for limited time

Tags: javascript, dhtml

im  try to use DHTML in order to make animation for 3-5 sec( the anumation supose to start from the left to the right...).

any idea how to do tthat???

```
//this one will set the the pictue on the right side of the screen
function setUpPicture() {
    subRunnerOBJ = new Object();
    subRunnerOBJ.topPos = 100;
    subRunnerOBJ.leftPos = 0;
    subRunnerOBJ.velX = 400;
    subRunnerOBJ.velY = 0;
    subRunnerOBJ.score = 0;
    hide1.style.visibility = "visible";
    hide1.style.left = subRunnerOBJ.leftPos + "px";
    hide1.style.top = subRunnerOBJ.topPos + "px";
    hide1.style.position = "absolute";
    //once we place the location of the sub , we will Call to new function that will move it
    startMovePicture();
}

function startMovePicture() {
    dt = 50; // in miliseconds
    h = setInterval("moveObj(subRunnerOBJ)", dt);
}

function moveObj(someObj) {
    counter = 0;
    while (counter < 30000) {
        subRunnerOBJ.leftPos = subRunnerOBJ.leftPos + subRunnerOBJ.velX * dt / 1000;
        subRunnerOBJ.topPos = subRunnerOBJ.topPos + subRunnerOBJ.velY * dt / 1000;
        hide1.style.left = subRunnerOBJ.leftPos + "px";
        hide1.style.top = subRunnerOBJ.topPos + "px";
        counter = counter + 50;
        if (counter == 3000) {
            stopRunning();
        }
    }
}

function stopRunning() {
    clearInterval(h);
    hide1.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

with this function i can see the picture for less than a sec...
how can i set the time here??

Answer (score 0):

Replace the milliseconds value with a number equal to the desired number of seconds, which would be 5000 for five seconds. Remove the while loop inside of `moveObj` and replace it by adding `clearInterval(h)` and  `hide1.style.visibility = "hidden";` as the last statement inside that block.